# Has_many :through association using 3 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models: `teacher`, `student` and `subject`.

I want to get the list of `Students` handled by the `teacher` in a particular `subject` and in params for `subject` I want to provide `subject_name`.

How can I do it using `has_many :through` association?
I tried this

teacher.rb

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subject_type
  has_many :students, :through=>:subject_type
end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subject_type
  has_many :teachers, :through=>:subject_type
end
```

subject.rb

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :subject_type
end
```

and a extra model is
subject_type.rb

```
class SubjectType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :student
end
```

controller for méthodes is 
analytics_controller.rb

```
class AnalyticsController < ApplicationController
  def get_students_by_teacher_through_subject
    s1 = Subject.find_by(subject_name:params[:subject_name])
    get_teacher = s1.teachers
    render json: get_teacher
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why you are passing `subject_name`, in params?  `subject_name` can be same, so at that time its may create issue for getting `id` from `subject_name`. its not good habit to pass `subject_name` , cau you pass `id` of `subject`?

Comment: “how can I do it”—as almost everything else—by writing the code that gets the parameter and returns a result.

Comment: Please add the relation between models and which is supposed to be the join table. What did you tried so far?

Comment: Model it explicitly, without relying on HABTM. If I was modeling it, it'd probably end up with a new model `class` which has many `students`, belongs to a `teacher` and `subject`, and also has a `year` or `semester` or whatever. While you _could_ make `teacher` HABTM `subjects` through `class`, that's not really going to help you with this.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails-3` **and** `ruby-on-rails-5`? Which version are you actually using?